# C# How does the following code for Low Pass Filter run?

Tags: c#, audio, naudio, lowpass-filter

I have the following C# code for Low pass filter found on NAudio site:

```
    public void setValues(ISampleProvider sourceProvider,int cutOffFreq)
    {
        this.sourceProvider = sourceProvider;
        this.cutOffFreq = cutOffFreq;

        filter_LowPass();
    }

    private void filter_LowPass()
    {
        channels = sourceProvider.WaveFormat.Channels;
        filters = new BiQuadFilter[channels];

        for (int n = 0; n < channels; n++)
            if (filters[n] == null)
                filters[n] = BiQuadFilter.LowPassFilter(44100, cutOffFreq, 1);
            else
                filters[n].SetLowPassFilter(44100, cutOffFreq, 1);
    }

    public WaveFormat WaveFormat { get { return sourceProvider.WaveFormat; } }

    public int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        int samplesRead = sourceProvider.Read(buffer, offset, count);

        for (int i = 0; i < samplesRead; i++)
            buffer[offset + i] = filters[(i % channels)].Transform(buffer[offset + i]);

        return samplesRead;
    }
```

Where is my read function being called?

Why do I need it?

I am calling the function filter_LowPass this way:

```
        myFilter.setValues(audioFileReader, currentCutOff);

        waveOut.Init(myFilter);
```

If I want to multiply each of my samples with a constant value after passing it through the low pass filter, where do I write the code?

Comment: Does the containing class implement any interfaces?

Comment: Yes, this one: ISampleProvider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NAudio is using a pull model here. The `waveOut` is going to be demanded samples by the sound card so it is going to call upstream to `myFilter.Read()`, which in turn is going to call `audioFileReader.Read()`.

If you want to add some extra gain you could either create a new ISampleProvider following the same pattern or inline it into the low pass filter's read function:

```
public int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    int samplesRead = sourceProvider.Read(buffer, offset, count);

    for (int i = 0; i < samplesRead; i++)
        buffer[offset + i] = gain * filters[(i % channels)].Transform(buffer[offset + i]);
        //                   ^^^^

    return samplesRead;
}
```

Comment: is gain = exp10((initial RMS of audio - new RMS after filtering) / 20) ?

Comment: I was just meaning to multiply it by whatever gain you want. 2.0 = 2x, etc...What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to equalize the samples...after passing them through a low pass filter, their power/intensity is decreasing leading to a reduction in volume...thus after low pass, i want to multiply each sample by a gain factor..but i dont know by how much i should..

Comment: It's not quite as simple as adding boost. There are 2 issues you need to consider. 1) imagine your signal was a full scale sine wave that was below your cutoff frequency, then the full scale signal would pass unattenuated through your filter and any gain you add is going to drive it into clipping. 2) if you add gain across the entire band by multiplying the entire signal you'll boost the noise in the section you just filtered out. It's better to apply boost to only the part of the spectrum you want. There are limits to what you can do with naudio. Try cascading a shelving filter.

Comment: my audio file is a recorded voice with no background noise...its just vocals...and all audio are well above my cutoff thresholds..so its safe for me to multiply the samples with a gain value :)

Comment: Will my value be `RMS(new) / RMS (old)`

Comment: Rms(old) / Rms(new) since new will be smaller the result will be >= 1.0. My point about the noise was that in the part of the spectrum that you've filtered out you will be boosting the noise floor up. If it's not a problem for you then don't worry about it.

Comment: Yes its not a problem for me :)..Are u sure about the formula?

Comment: Yes. if you measure the rms of the entire input file and the rms of the entire filtered waveform then the gain is rms(original)/rms(filtered) and you can multiply each filtered sample by that value to get the same final rms.

Comment: But theoreticallt gain is always output/input right?

Comment: Yes that's right. But since you're wanting to cancel its effect you need to multiply by it's reciprocal.